# How can I do an iterative comparison of current row with both previous and next rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

Is there some smart or Pythonic way to do something like the following in Pandas?

```
for index, row in pd.DataFrame().iterrows():
    if (row[previous_index]>=row and row[next_index]>=row):
       row=(row[previous_index]+row[next_index])/2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could implement this for Series using `rolling_apply`. It's unclear how your comparisons would work on a whole *row* in a DataFrame.

```
In [5]: s = Series([1,2,3,2,5])

In [6]: def f(rows):
    if (rows[0] >= rows[1]) and (rows[2] >= rows[1]):
        return (rows[0] + rows[2]) / 2
    else:
        return rows[1]
   ...:     

In [7]: pd.rolling_apply(s, 3, f, center=True)
Out[7]: 
0   NaN
1     2
2     3
3     4
4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what operation you want to perform on the rows, but the `shift` method would suit you. (There is both `Series.shift` and `DataFrame.shift`.)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
ser = pd.Series(np.random.random_integers(0,10,10))

shift_down_by_one = ser.shift(1)
shift_up_by_one = ser.shift(-1)

mask = (shift_up_by_one >= ser) & (shift_down_by_one >= ser)
ser.loc[mask] = (shift_up_by_one + shift_down_by_one) / 2
```